# 30 iOS devices downloading 90 files in queue, starting at the same time - bugs up. Works fine one-by-one

Tags: ios, network-programming, download, afnetworking

I have a download queue setup in my code using AFNetworking and batchEnqueue, with 5 max simultaneous connections (have tried with 1 too). This queue works perfectly when run from device at a time, however I am trying to start the process of downloading a 90 file long queue on 30 devices (connected to the same Wi-Fi) at the same time. This causes a lot of the downloads to timeout and generally pretty much makes the download process halt on all devices. If run device-by-device in queue they all complete fine at pretty much max download speed. Could it be my Wi-Fi that can't handle the lot of the connections at once, my server, or could it be they way I wrote my iOS code to handle the queue?

Comment: The Wifi can handle that - but the bandwidth must be shared.  Your server? I don't know. Usually, "the big" servers can handle a lot of connections. However, if you have a development setup for your web service on your local machine, it might be single threaded and synchronous - thus effectively serializing the connection requests.

Comment: Good to know the wifi can handle it. The server, I have just been told, has an nginx hardcoded limit of max 32 simultaneous connections from one IP, but they told me that normally a keep-alive makes this limit almost impossible to hit. Could it maybe have something to do with this? I have only tested with 4 devices so far, and still it seems to be a problem.

Comment: You need to investigate the issue. I would start setting the maxConcurrentOperations to 1. When dealing with large response data, the bandwidth becomes the limiting factor anyway. Setup NSLogs in connection:didReceiveData and log the size of the transmitted data chunk. Examine the behavior when you add devices. Sure, you can always have issues with Wifi. Tracking down subtle issues is difficult and requires a package trace log and tools (tcpdump, Wireshark and friends) Good luck! ;)